Help me find drarry fic with jealous draco rewrite Please
It's almost a rewrite of their years growing up, but with draco as harry's friend. ron is the way he is such as not believe ing harry, and getting jealous of his status. i remember draco getting upset because ron and harry made up. i also think this was around the time of the tournament too. draco was just really hurt by harry befriending ron again. draco and ron dong get along, and i believe they argue constantly. draco is always scoffing at him and anything he says. i believe ron was also being really nasty to hermoine and draco also couldn't forgive him for that. he says time and time again that ron is a terrible friend.  that's all i can remember sorry it's so vague!! i remember really enjoying it, but can't remember more other than jealousy.!!

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Where and when did you read this?

It definitely had to be within this year or the last year. Though, I do think it's an older fic!
